# html form not submitting and reopening same page

Tags: php, html, forms

I am quite new to programming and am trying to set up a simple test form that is supposed to add or subtract the two numbers given. I have done it several times and it's always worked well. This one, I can't figure out what is wrong. When I hit submit, it reopens the same page in another tab.

Code for the form (html)

```
<form id="envio" target="formulario2p.php" method="POST">


Ingrese primer valor:                   <br>
            <input type="text" name="valor1" id="valor1" />
                <br>
        Ingrese segundo valor:                  <br>
            <input type="text" name="valor2" id="valor2" />
                <br>
    Indique operacion:                  <br>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="suma"/> sumar
            <br>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="resta"/> restar
            <br>
        <input type="submit" value="operar"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
        $valor1=$_POST["valor1"];
        $valor2=$_POST['valor2'];
        $radio1=$_POST["radio1"];

        echo $valor1; echo $valor2;
        if($radio1=="suma")
            {$suma=$valor1 + $valor2; 
            echo "la suma es ".$suma;}
        else {
            $resta=$valor1 - $valor2; 
            echo "la resta es ".$resta;
        }           

                ?>
```

Comment: Target determines the window or tab the form's response is displayed in, not the script to process the data.

Comment: right. as in target="_blank" for a new tab. would there be any case in which what I originally wrote could be correct?

Comment: Probably not.  You almost always want to specify an action; otherwise the action defaults to the current document.  Unless your current document can both display and process the form - possible, but not recommended - you want to specify the action of the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify action:

You are doing:

```
<form id="envio" target="formulario2p.php" method="POST">
```

Should be

```
<form id="envio" action="formulario2p.php" method="POST">
```

`target` attribute specifies where to open a new documents. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp 
`action` specifies which url to send the form data to. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Answer (score 1):

You are missing action in your form. You may try:

```
<form id="envio" action="formulario2p.php" method="POST">
...
</form>
```